# Armenian HM QWERTY keyboard - where's Շշ (sh)?

Tags: macos, input-source

Here's screenshot of available keys in Armenian HM QWERTY keyboard:

[image]

The thing that bothers me a lot - I can not find the "Շ" letter ("sh").
For instance, here's screenshot of the second keyboard available - Armenian Western QWERTY (Շ is marked with red dot):

[image]

So, the question is, how should I time sh on HM QWERTY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Շ is at option + shift + s on HM Qwerty.  շ is at option + s.

You can use Keyboard Viewer to find such things

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13746

Comment: Wow! Quite strange since sh is quite common in Armenian. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: @shabunc  Is there perhaps a dialect where this character is a lot less common?  It seems odd to have two qwerty keyboards, one called "western", for this language.

Comment: indeed, there are two major dialects, Western and Eastern but sh is used in both with the same frequency. OK, may be just some historical reasons.

Comment: It would be fairly simple to make a custom layout which puts that character in a better place using http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele